# Aplicar lambda where a DataSet en Asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema y gracias por su ayuda.

Tengo un menú dinámico(Todo desde base de datos),el cual le paso como parámetro el usuario y tengo un DataSet el cual me regresa dos Tablas. La segunda table que me regresa es la del Menú.

A este Dataset quiero aplicarle una expresión lambda pero me marca error espero me puedan ayudar trabajo en asp.net c# 3 capas.

Aquí coloco mi código.

```
  public DataSet MenuSubmenu(string Usuario)
    {

        SqlParameter sqlparameter = new SqlParameter("@Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar); //Aqui le paso el parametro
        sqlparameter.Value = Usuario; // Le paso la variable que esta arriba
        return _conexion.ExecuteDataset("MenuUsuario", sqlparameter).Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.Field<int>("idMenu_Padre")==0); // Aqui solo le paso el nombre del Procedimiento almacenado llamado MenuUsuario y el parametro ademas de aplicar la expresion lamba 
    }
```

Me marca estos dos errores.

```
Error   3   No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Data.DataSet' en 'System.Data.DataTable'

Error   2   No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' en 'System.Data.DataSet'
```

Alguien sabe como aplicar esta expresión lambda.

Gracias.

Comment: primero agrega una comprobacion que estas recibiendo datos datos= _conexion.ExecuteDataset("MenuUsuario", sqlparameter)  despues puedes convertir a tabla if (datos.Tables.Count > 1) { //mayor a uno considerando que esperas al menos dos tablas.

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate si entiendo pero una pregunta ¿Como quedaría la expresión lambda aplicando el Where como en el código de arriba? Gracias.

Comment: la expresion se ve bien; primero la tabla var tabla=  (DataTable)_conexion.ExecuteDataset("MenuUsuario", sqlparameter).Tables[1]; despues return tabla.AsEnumerable().Where(m => m.Field<int>("idMenu_Padre")==0); como puedes ver lo nuevo solo es la conversion implicita (DataTable). Aparte seguro que es Tables[1] y no Tables[0]?

Comment: Gracias @MiguelZarate me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando usas `Tables[1]` estas accediendo solo a un `DataTable`, es por eso que el `Where()` aplica solo a este y es lo que retorna, no estas devolviendo un `Dataset` sino solo el `DataTable` donde aplicas el linq.

Quizas debas cambiar la firma a

```
public DataTable MenuSubmenu(string Usuario){ ...
```

Sino recomendaria que lo dejes asi

```
public DataSet MenuSubmenu(string Usuario)
{

    SqlParameter sqlparameter = new SqlParameter("@Usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar); 
    sqlparameter.Value = Usuario; 

    return _conexion.ExecuteDataset("MenuUsuario", sqlparameter);
}
```

Y luego aplicas el filtro cuando lo usas

```
DataSet ds = MenuSubmenu("xx");

DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(m => m.Field<int>("idMenu_Padre")==0);
```

en la respuesta es que trabajas los datos aplicando filtro